# How to extract all text before first numeric character only in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a variable x that is a series of characters such as:

```
"W1W", "BT3", "BS5", "E1W", "B68"
```

From this I need to extract the characters before the first numeric character to get e.g.

```
"W", "BT", "BS", "E", "B"
```

I have tried looking through previous questions and found:

`gsub("[^a-zA-Z]", "", x)`

but this keeps the text characters following the numeric character and results in:

```
"WW", "BT", "BS", "EW", "B"
```

Is there any way to get only the leading text characters before the numeric character and drop everything afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
sub("^(\\D+).*", "\\1", x)
```

If there must be a digit and the digits can be at the start (and you need empty values then), use

```
sub("^(\\D*)\\d.*", "\\1", x)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Elpiea/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/Elpiea/2)

The regex matches

- `^` - start of string
- `(\D*)` - 0+ non-digit symbol
- `\d` - a digit
- `.*` - any 0+ chars to the end of the string

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- c("W1W", "BT3", "BS5", "E1W", "B68")

library(stringr)

str_extract(x, "^\\D+")

# [1] "W"  "BT" "BS" "E"  "B"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `regmatches/regexpr` from `base R`

```
regmatches(x, regexpr("\\D+(?=\\d)", x, perl = TRUE))
#[1] "W"  "BT" "BS" "E"  "B"
```

#### data

```
x <- c("W1W", "BT3", "BS5", "E1W", "B68")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `x` in the Note at the end, remove everything from the first digit onwards:

```
sub("\\d.*", "", x)
## [1] "W"  "BT" "BS" "E"  "B"
```

### Note

```
x <- c("W1W", "BT3", "BS5", "E1W", "B68")
```